# Problemas con where anidados en Query Builder Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo el inconveniente cuando paso parámetros vacios en un filtro. Estoy usando un scope donde filtro por varios parametros, entre ellos  año, mes, provincia, y nombre.

Sobre Nombre no hay problemas ya que utilizo un like. Pero en los demas cuando filtro, los parámetros son opcionales. Puedo filtrar por todos o por algunos. Pero aqui la cuestion cuando filtro por alguno y dejo otro vacio. este where q busca sobre un vacio y no lo encuentra, me hace la consulta vacia.

la primer solucion que se me ocurre es un engorroso if anidados con las 9 opciones(ya que son 3 posibilidades de vacio) y poniendo en cada 1 los where q no estan vacios... Quiero creer q hay una solucion mejor

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{

    if($request->nombre == "" && $request->provincia_id == "" && $request->meses =="" && $request->anio == "")
            return $query
                    ->where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now());


    return $query
                ->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$request->nombre%")
                ->whereMonth('fecha', $request->meses)
                ->whereYear('fecha', $request->anio);
                //->where('provincia_id','=',"$request->provincia_id");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya es casi un habito responder mis propias preguntas. Pero creo que la solucion puede contribuir

Buscando y uniendo piezas encontré que se puede hacer un where como función y dentro de el hacer los if usando la clase abstracta de Input. Asi que:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{

    if($request->nombre == "" && $request->provincia_id == "" && $request->meses =="" && $request->anio == "")
            return $query
                    ->where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now());

    $eventos= Evento::where(function($query) use($request) {

     if(Input::has('provincia_id'))
        $query->where('provincia_id','=',"$request->provincia_id");

     if(Input::has('meses'))
        $query->whereMonth('fecha', $request->meses);

    if(Input::has('anio'))
        $query->whereYear('fecha', $request->anio);

    if(Input::has('nombre'))
        $query->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$request->nombre%");

     });

    return $eventos;
}
```

hay que usar el Fascades

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Basicamente verifica cada input con su id y si tiene algun dato (en mi caso eran select pero funciona igual), si lo hay ejecuta el query sino pasa de largo.

No seria necesario usar el scope, podes usarlo en el controlador. Tengo que investigar si es la forma mas prolija. Pero pareciera que si

Comment: muy bueno tu ejemplo...mi pregunta es..como se puede hacer lo mismo si la consulta incluye joins de tablas?